# How to definitely disable validations in JSP files in Eclipse Ganymede

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-3.4

I am using Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2 as my primary IDE and I am facing a really frustrating problem from time to time.

Eclipse is getting really slow (I mean, REALLY slow, almost unusable) while validating the JSP code I am working on. I am using Struts 1 as my Web App Framework and jQuery as my JS library.

Is there a real way to disable/turn off Eclipse validations for JSP files only?

I went in Window > Preferences > Validation and unchecked JSP Content Validator and JSP Syntax Validator. Even if I uncheck everything related to HTML, JavaScript, JSP.... name it... Eclipse is still displaying some syntax errors (X marks, red underlines, that are in fact false positives as I am generating dynamic portion of code using Struts logic:equals tags.

I get the problem while working on complex JSPs files, and I got a decent laptop, so it is really an Eclipse problem. Restarting Eclipse usually fixes the problem for a while.

Thank you

Charles

Comment: Are you letting projects override the workspace defaults?

Comment: Well, I don't really know as I never changed that setting. I guess no? What is the default value?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you.  It always seemed backwards to me in terms of how it's presented, saying whether projects can override the default rather than just having the project manage whether it's overriding the default.